# Iterate millions of rows in pandas optimally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

What I am looking for is to put for each ID the most current description (as long as it is not an empty cell, and if it’s is empty, it should be the first non-empty description). I have sorted the DF by ID and by Date, so for each ID "group", the first description is the most current.

The problem comes when I have to take that description and replace it in the rest of the rows of the same ID. The process with a FOR loop takes me more than 30 minutes, so I need a much more efficient solution.

So far, my procedure has been:

- list unique IDs
- Iterate with a loop for those IDs, and with a '.loc' take out the description field:
- If the most recent description is null, I put an `if` to catch the second description field

```py
for id in list(df.columnaid.unique()):  
    
    if df.loc[(df.columnaid == id).description.unique()[0] != "":
        description = df.loc[(df.columnaid == id).description.unique()[0]
        
        
    elif df.loc[(df.columnaid == id).description.unique()[0] == "" and len(df.loc[(df.columnaid == id).description.unique()) >1:
        description = df.loc[(df.columnaid == id).description.unique()[1]
```

- Save the ID product and the description in a dictionary:

```
dicc[id] = dicc.get(id, description)
```

Then, with a`.loc`, an `.isin` and a `map` I replace the values obtained in the description column
This procedure Works, but it’s not optimal at all, and I need to know how could it be done a better way without taking more than 30 min.

```
df.loc[df['columnaid'].isin(dicc.keys()), 'description'] = df['columnaid'].map(dicc)
```

An example of the DataFrame (it would be the same but with millions of rows) is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"columnaid": ["2321fdsf", "2321fdsf", "3gsdfer3", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "7fg45d"],
                 "date": ["2022-11-16","2022-10-07","2022-09-02","2021-12-04","2021-09-23","2021-03-06","2021-03-15"],
                 "description": ["aaa", "bbb", "abc", "eee", "", "aqwert", "yuiop"],
                 })



    columnaid      date     description
0   2321fdsf    2022-11-16  aaa
1   2321fdsf    2022-10-07  bbb
2   3gsdfer3    2022-09-02  abc
3   4gdsfg44    2021-12-04  eee
4   4gdsfg44    2021-09-23  
5   4gdsfg44    2021-03-06  aqwert
6   7fg45d      2021-03-15  yuiop
```

The outcome should be:

```
    columnaid      date     description
0   2321fdsf    2022-11-16  aaa
1   2321fdsf    2022-10-07  aaa
2   3gsdfer3    2022-09-02  abc
3   4gdsfg44    2021-12-04  eee
4   4gdsfg44    2021-09-23  eee
5   4gdsfg44    2021-03-15  eee
6   7fg45d      2021-03-06  yuiop
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing – use `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "columnaid": ["2321fdsf", "2321fdsf", "3gsdfer3", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "7fg45d"],
        "date": ["2022-11-16", "2022-10-07", "2022-09-02", "2021-12-04", "2021-09-23", "2021-03-06", "2021-03-15"],
        "description": ["aaa", "bbb", "abc", "eee", "", "aqwert", "yuiop"],
    }
)

# Convert date so we can `idxmax` it
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# Find newest descriptions per columnaid into an indexed series
newest_descriptions = df.groupby("columnaid").apply(lambda x: x.loc[x["date"].idxmax(), "description"])
# (Print for debugging)
print(newest_descriptions)

# Map the descriptions back into the original df
df["description"] = df["columnaid"].map(newest_descriptions)

print(df)
```

This prints out

```
columnaid
2321fdsf      aaa
3gsdfer3      abc
4gdsfg44      eee
7fg45d      yuiop
dtype: object

  columnaid       date description
0  2321fdsf 2022-11-16         aaa
1  2321fdsf 2022-10-07         aaa
2  3gsdfer3 2022-09-02         abc
3  4gdsfg44 2021-12-04         eee
4  4gdsfg44 2021-09-23         eee
5  4gdsfg44 2021-03-06         eee
6    7fg45d 2021-03-15       yuiop
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand or you are overthinking. Your question can be done in three simple steps.

```
#drop n/a
dfn = df.dropna(subset=['description']).copy()

#now you have a clean `dfn` simply sort then pickup the 1st observation in each group
uniq = dfn.groupby('columnaid')['description'].first().reset_index('first_obs')

#now you can merge uniq back to df
df = pd.merge(df, uniq, how='left', on='columnaid')
```

The column `first_obs` is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

In the Spanish version, @HeytalePazguato found a very fast and optimal solution, which takes less than a second to do what it needed.

I'll leave it here in case anyone ever needs it. All credit to him.

If you read this, @HeytalePazguato, thank you very much again.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"columnid": ["2321fdsf", "2321fdsf", "3gsdfer3", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "4gdsfg44", "7fg45d", "7fg45d"],
                 "date": ["2022-11-16","2022-10-07","2022-09-02","2021-12-04","2021-09-23","2021-03-06", "2022-05-13","2021-03-15"],
                 "description": ["aaa", "bbb", "abc", "eee", "", "aqwert", "", "yuiop"],
                 })

df["description"] = df["description"].replace("", np.nan)

df["description"] = df.groupby(by = "columnid")['description'].transform('first')
df
```

The result:

```
   columnid        date description
0  2321fdsf  2022-11-16         aaa
1  2321fdsf  2022-10-07         aaa
2  3gsdfer3  2022-09-02         abc
3  4gdsfg44  2021-12-04         eee
4  4gdsfg44  2021-09-23         eee
5  4gdsfg44  2021-03-06         eee
6    7fg45d  2022-05-13       yuiop
7    7fg45d  2021-03-15       yuiop
```